# The .htaccess redirect with parameters $1 and $2 to form URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to complete the following rule in my .htaccess.
I have this .htaccess in root directory of domain1.com and want to arrange the following redirect domain1.com/index.php?domain2.com?page.html which will bring all visitors to domain2.com/page.html.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^
RewriteRule (.+)\.php\?(.+)\?(.+) http://$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Solved.
domain1.com/domain2.com/page.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^
RewriteRule (.+)\/(.+) http://$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is this source URL fixed: `domain1.com/index.php?domain2.com?page.html`? Is that second `?` really necessary? You could make this easier for yourself by constructing a more "valid" URL.

Comment: This part is flexible: "domain1.com/index.php?domain2.com?page.html" but it must contain "domain2.com" and "page.html".
And "?" is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constructing your initial URLs like `domain1.com/index.php?domain2.com?page.html` - which requires you to capture two separate backreferences (the second `?` will be URL encoded). It would be better to format your URL more conventionally, like the following instead:

```
domain1.com.com/index.php?redirect=domain2.com/page.html
```

(Not sure why you were substituting a `?` for the first slash in the URL being passed?)

Then you could do something like the following. Note that you need to use a condition that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirect=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%1 [QSD,R,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the last matched *CondPattern*.

The `QSD` flag is required to discard the original query string from the request.

HOWEVER, you need to perform additional validation on the domains that can be redirected to, otherwise this will likely be abused for malicious intent once it is discovered.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^
> RewriteRule (.+)\/(.+) http://$1/$2 [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteCond` directive here isn't doing anything. If you are wanting to validate that a `Host` header is present (ie. is not a HTTP/1.0 request) then you should change the regex `^` to `.` (simply a dot). However, if you are on a shared server then this test is probably redundant.

By using the URl-path, this will "break" if the destination hostname is the same as the source.